# Why bootstrap not load font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have two pages, the fist is login page. In that page the font load well like this:

[image: demonstration]

But in the second page (after login) the font didn't loaded, I don't know why.

[image: demonstration]

Here is code my login page:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="./js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Online Learning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="font-family: cursive;">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the secod page:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- None of these css and js do any thing with font face -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/teacher/teacher_layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/teacher/materials_teacher.css">
<script src="./js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/js_layout.js"></script>
<script src="./js/materials_teacher.js"></script>

<title>Teacher-Materials</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- I'm sure this include file wont affect -->
    <%@include file="./common/header.jsp" %>
    <div class="row content_body">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** In second page: this line `<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-remove"></span>` rendering nothing (empty), but in the fist page it rendering 'X' icon.

**EDIT2:** After change the second page like this, its still not load font:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="./js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Teacher-Materials</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-remove">a</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You defined the font style as `style="font-family: cursive;"` in the first page but not the second?

Comment: yes, in the fist page

Comment: Sooo... is that why the font is different?  If it's not, I would remove all the extra CSS files from the second page, and add them back one-by-one.  That will help you narrow down where the problem is.  Most likely one of the other CSS files is using a different font style for the  elements on the page.

Comment: The fonts will only be loaded if you actually use them on the page.

Comment: @Marks I was tried remove all the extra CSS files, but nothing change, it still not load font

Comment: @Matthew Please see my edit :( .

Comment: On the first page, you have `font-family: cursive;` defined, which references your font. On the second page, you do not have this defined and since you aren't using the font, it won't load the font file.

Comment: thank for your hint, but i tried to put font-family into second page, and nothing change, it isn't problem :(

Comment: i dont know why it not even render the square

Answer (score 0):

Awwwww, finally got this sand of a beach! spend my half of day.

This span code provide by http://glyphicons.com/ does not match with code provide by bootstrap, look at this test:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="./js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Teacher-Materials</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="font-family: cursive;">
 <div>
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">a</span>
        </div>
        <div>
              <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-remove">a</span>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```